# Jquery Accordion Requires 2 clicks in IE7~9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, accordion

for some reason the accordion that I implemented doesn't work smoothly in IE 7 to 9
they always require a extra click before the thing starts to work.

once it is working no more extra click is required to toggle between hide and show.

does anyone have any idea how to fix this issue?

```
<div class="container_inner row-fluid accordion-group"">
        <div class="accordion-heading accordion-scrolldown">
            <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
                <p class="span4">text</p><p class="span4">text</p><p class="span4">text</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-body in collapse" style="float: left; width: 100%; height: auto;" id="collapseOne">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                <div class="span4"> 
                        content1</div>
                <div class="span4"> 
                        content2</div>
                <div class="span4">
                        content3</div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and here is the inti

```
$j( ".accordion .accordion_inner" ).accordion({
        animate: "swing",
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
        icons: "",
        heightStyle: "content"
    });
```

Comment: Maybe adding your code would enable someone to answer this question . . .

Comment: @PatDobson This is the basic structure of my code. the inti is somewhere else I will have to look for and post

Comment: You have some very strange markup there. Your accordion structure looks rather unorthodox, and I don't think I've ever seen 3 paragraphs in a single anchor in my life. :-) Also, your selector in the accordion init function is completely wrong. Here it is (sort of) fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/JSMgx I suggest that you go back to the jQueryUI docs and try again.